# The dust (settle or settles)

Tags: grammar, idioms, expressions

There is the idiom "[the dust settle(s)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dust-settles)" which is used to indicate that after an argument or big change, the situation becomes calmer. The question is that why the verb "settle" varies in different structures?
Please have a look on the following sentences:

1. ***Let*** the dust **settle**!
2. ***When*** the dust **settle's'**...

**Example 1:

> - We should ***let* the dust** **settle** from the recent scandal before we make any major policy decisions.

**Example 2:

> - We should only start painting ***when* the du**st **settles** after construction is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction "**let** + *object* + *verb*" takes its verb in the bare infinitive form. This is similar in structure, although not necessarily in meaning, to modal verbs which take main verbs in the infinitive (he **goes**; he **must go**).

> The dust settles.

Here, "settles" is the correct conjugated form of the verb "settle" (for the subject "the dust").

> Let the dust settle.

Here, the "let" construction requires a bare infinitive, which is "settle."

This may make it clearer:

> - He **is**. Let him **be**.
> - They **are**. Let them **be**.
> - I **am**. Let me **be**.

Answer (score 2):

Don't get distracted by the idiom  - this is completely standard English syntax.

When we use the verb *let*, the next verb should be a *bare infinitive*.

Ex:

*The girl sat down*
*We let the girl **sit** down*

*The boy goes home*
*Let the boy **go** home*

*The dust settles*
*Let the dust **settle***

The noun *dust* is a *mass noun*, like *water* - it refers to an uncountable amount of a substance.  Like other mass nouns, *dust* is treated as a singular noun.

Ex:

*The water **is** warm*
*The rice **goes** in the pot*

*The dust **settles***

Answer (score 1):

“Let the dust settle” is imperative, where the main verb is always in the same form as the bare infinitive.

“The dust settles” is present simple, so it gets the “-s” for third person singular.